# visual studio 2015 windows forms c# inconsistent size of controls between versions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am making a desktop application and when i use it on my pc it works fine and looks like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/1c152aed25bee8a595dfa062db7277de.png

but when i share the program with another friend it looks like this:

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wdw39s3p9zeajeu/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-08-30%2014.38.14.png

Why it happend? how can i fix it?

I use win10 and .Net 4.6.2, my friends use win 8 or win 7 and .Net 4.5 or 4.6.2, I configurated the project to be compatible with win 8 and .Net 4.5 (visual studio 2015 doesnt have an option to make compatibility with win 7).

Comment: Take a look at: [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx) or this one: [Layout in Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229674(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Look at the machines' font scaling. If one machine is set to 100% and the other to 125/150% then it will not look the same. Depending on how you layout your controls, you may see some weirdness. You need to properly set your Application's Forms/Controls AutoScaleMode so it scales properly. Even then, you may see some weirdness. Have you considered WPF? I think WPF scales better than WinForm. You may have to drive down to each individual control to fix scaling issues. Again, this depends on how you layout your controls.

Comment: In addition to @TomA's comment concerning AutoScaleMode (I'd recommend DPI or None), also configure your application to be DPI Aware.  Click, Project Menu->Add New Item->General-> Application Manifest File.  Near the end of the file you will see a tag `<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">`.  Un-comment that tag to declare that application as dpiAware.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some weirdness with different machine font sizing and this adversely effected how things were laid out.

First thing to check on your forms and all UserControls, make sure their AutoScaleMode is set to Font.

If that alone doesn't resolve it, try setting the font size of your form or user controls in their constructor, especially if you're not using the default font. I'll keep looking for the StackOverflow answer that lead me to that, but it's worth trying. The reason that helps is that the autoscaling happens before the font size is set. If you look in the designer.cs file, you'll see the font size is set after any scaling occurs.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `Form` `AutoScaleMode` to None
2. Set `Form` `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`
3. As an additional check, check if `Anchor` property is set to `Left` and `Top` for the controls.

HTH.